# put variable into an a href tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a variable into a link for jquery, but everything I tried didnt work.

Here is an example below.

```
let url = "www.google.com?s=" + id;
$("#test").append("<a href='+url+'>Test</a>");
```

Comment: Missing quotes to delimit string parts `$("#test").append("<a href='" +url+ "'>Test</a>");`

Comment: Your IDE (and the SO snippet) will show you what's a string and what's a variable - you have just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

**For ES6:**

```js
let url = "www.google.com?s=" + id;
$("#test").append(`<a href='${url}'>Test</a>`);
```

**For ES5**

```js
let url = "www.google.com?s=" + id;
$("#test").append("<a href='" + url + "'>Test</a>");
```

I hope it helps to you.